# AGPL 3.0 compatibility

Tags: license-compatibility, agpl-3.0

I want to use AGPL to licence my project. But I need learn AGPL compatibility with these 3 licences:

- Android Software Development Kit License
- Fabric Software and Services Agreement
- Crashlytics Terms of Service

I want to use Fabric library (Fabric Software and Services Agreement, Crashlytics Terms of Service) and com.google.android.gms:play-services (Android Software Development Kit License).

I checked https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html. But I could not find an information about the compatibility of these 3 licenses.

Do these 3 licenses comply with AGPL? If incompatible, will the project license be invalid?

Comment: For faster and exact answers, could you provide links to the license text?